# Session management in Rails (2.3)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-2

Apparently, after upgrading to Rails 2.3 my session storage has stopped working. I used to have this:

session :session_expires => 3.years.from_now

in my application_controller.rb, but now every time i close the browser (chrome) the session expires. I read from somewhere that session_expires would have changed to expire_after, but

session :expire_after => 3.years.from_now

didn't do any good eihter.

Answer (score 3):

Ok, don't know why "session :expire_after => ..." didn't work, but i got it working with this:

ActionController::Base.session_options[:expire_after] = 3.years

Comment: Sweet worked for me (not it's no longer browser session).  Either setting it explicitly there or within the ActionController::Base.session = {} block both worked (within config/initializers/session_store.rb

Answer (score 2):

Place this into your ApplicationController and just as your session expires a new one will be generated.

```
  before_filter :change_session_expiration_time

  def change_session_expiration_time    
      request.session_options[:expire_after] = 1.minute
  end
```